# What is the meaning of "Eagle cries"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, idioms

So I'm listening to this song by Joe Cocker & Jennifer Warnes called "Up Where We Belong".
There is a verse:

> Love lift us up where we belong, **Where the eagles cry**, On a mountain high

I searched and found out there are some other songs containing:

> **When The Eagle Cries**

I don't understand the meaning. So is it a metaphor for something or is it an expression?

Comment: Please see the [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/cry) definition "**cry³** (of a bird or other animal) make a loud characteristic call. *Overhead, a bird cried, and in the distance, another answered.*"

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you. I did take a look but unfortunately I don't think none of them fits in this context.

Comment: In the olden days, long before social media, we had a [**Town Crier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_crier) who wasn't usually sad, but possibly even joyful. Oyez!

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I'm not following!

Comment: The Town Crier wasn't the local saddo shedding tears, but was paid to make public announcements. Here's another usage: "[**hue and cry**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hue_and_cry) A loud clamour or public outcry."

Comment: @WeatherVane This makes sense. Thank you. Could you please write this in the answer box so I can accept it?

Comment: It's fairly literal.  The eagle is making his/her characteristic cry/call/squawk sound.  https://youtu.be/9RArGl2vkGI

Comment: The sharp call of the eagle is exciting - out in nature on a mountain, hearing the sounds of the wild, and feeling that love lifts your spirits along with all the rest. So, three senses uplifted in one lyric: love (kinetic lift), eagle (audio lift) and mountain (visual lift).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use of **cry** here isn't about sadness, which being in a song lyric might suggest.

The relevant Lexico definition is

> **cry**
>   VERB
>
> **3** (of a bird or other animal) make a loud characteristic call.
>   *Overhead, a bird cried, and in the distance, another answered.*

There is another usage in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_crier) of an old job, long before social media, of

> **Town Crier**
>
> The town crier was used to make public announcements in the streets.

He was paid to go around town town shouting out news for all to hear.

Yet another usage is [this phrase](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hue_and_cry)

> **hue and cry**
>   PHRASE
>
> **1** A loud clamour or public outcry.